# On new Mac, Chrome is not showing pages as HTML by default when file extension is missing

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a new Mac with latest Chrome in developer mode and url's that are missing the .html are not being displayed as HTML until I manually add the .html to the end of the url. What can I do to make it display any file missing the .html as HTML by default?

Comment: Are you asking about configuring how your browser handles files accessed with a `file://` scheme URI or configuring how your HTTP server handles files it is serving over an `http://` scheme URI?

Comment: It appears that the issue was that I was running some chrome extensions in incognito mode and is hopefully fixed now

Answer (score -1):

You can't. If you type in your URL it will display that and only that URL. Notice there can be URLs not ending with .html but with .htm or .xhtml or .php or .asp etc.